# About a partial converse to the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I've been reading the GTM text *Topics in Banach Space Theory* by Albaic and Kalton. In the appendix, it states the following partial converse to the Banach-Steinhaus theorem:

> Let $\{S_n\}$ be a sequence of operators from a Banach space $X$ into a normed linear space $Y$ such that $\sup_n\|S_n\|<\infty$.  Then if $T:X\to Y$ is another operator, the subspace
>   \begin{align*}
> M=\{x\in X:\|S_nx-Tx\|\to0\}
> \end{align*}
>   is norm-closed in $X$.

I came up with the following proof of this result:

> Put $K=\sup_n\|S_n\|$, let $x_0$ be a limit point of $M$, and let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. There exists $x\in M$ such that 
>   \begin{align*}
> \|x-x_0\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(K+\|T\|)}.
> \end{align*}
>   For this $x$, there is some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
>   \begin{align*}
> \|S_nx-Tx\|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}
> \end{align*}
>   for $n\geq N$. For such $n$, we have
>   \begin{align*}
> \|S_nx_0-Tx_0\|&\leq \|S_nx-Tx\|+\|S_n+T\|\cdot\|x_0-x\| \\
> &<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
> \end{align*}
>   Thus $\|S_nx_0-Tx_0\|\to0$, and therefore $x_0\in M$. QED

However, in my proof the assumption that $X$ be a Banach space appears unnecessary.  So my question is somewhat twofold:  Is there something I overlooked in my proof? If not, is the assumption that $X$ is complete superfluous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $\{T, S_1, S_2, \ldots\}$ is a uniformly continuous family of maps from metric space $X$ to metric space $Y$, then $\{x \in X: \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) = T(x)\}$ is closed.  This does not require completeness of either metric space.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is fine, besides the typo where it should be $(\|S_n\|+\|T\|)$ instead of $\|S_n+T\|$.

And I don't think you need for $X$ to be complete.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I guess the authors just added the completeness hypothesis since it is stated as a partial converse to a statement where completeness is necessary.